# Core i7 3770k not working on chinese motherboard Machinist B75 Pro U5

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

I have a Chinese manufactured motherboard Machinist B75 Pro U5. According to the manual (very hard to find by the way, didn't comes in the box):

> "Supports Intel Core i3/i5/i7 2th or 3th generation, Xeon E3 v2, Pentium and Celeron series processors"

Now is working fine with a i5 3470s CPU. For gaming it works really good actually.

I just got a new i7 3770k CPU and I have installed it, but here comes the problem. 1 second after turn the PC on, **4 beeps** can be heard: no video, no boot, no BIOS.

I thought may be the CPU is damaged or dead, so i put it in another old hp office class computer (HP Compaq Pro 4300, the one where i have removed the current i5 3470s CPU in the first place) with the same socket (LGA 1155). For my surprise, the i7 3770k CPU works fine in this junk. So we can discard the CPU as a problem.

##### Working Around:

1. According to [UserBenchmark](https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Machinist-B75-PRO/246887) and [cpu-upgrade](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/B75_Express.html) websites, i7 3770k is compatible with this motherboard
2. According to Intel Ark, [i7 3770k](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/65523/intel-core-i73770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz/specifications.html)'s main differences with [i5 3470s](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/68315/intel-core-i53470s-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz/specifications.html) are: Total Threads (8 vs 4), base frequency (3.50 vs 2.90 GHz), cache size (8 vs 6 MB) and power consumption (77 vs 65 watts). **The last one makes me wonder if this can be the issue**.
3. The "official" [Machinist website](https://machinistofficial.com/products/machinist-lga-1155-motherboard-b75-micro-atx-computer-motherboards-for-desktop-pc-intel-2th-3th-gen-pcie-2-0-ngff-m-2-pci-ddr3-sata-6gb-s-usb-3-0-for-core-i3-i5-i7-xeon-e3-v2-pentium), says it works with the i7 3770k.
4. If i put back the i5 3470s CPU into the motherboard, starts with 4 beeps and boot with no problem... after restart, no beeps can be heard again. It seems like it use this beeps as a warning in case some hardware changes.
5. I can't find any "beeps meaning" table or documentation in internet nor the motherboard manual.

##### Current Setup:

- Machinist B75 Pro U5 Motherboard
- 700w Power Supply
- Nvidia RTX 2060 GPU
- 1 M.2 NGFF, 1 SSD and 2 HDD Units
- 2 x 8GB Fury HyperX 1866mhz DDR3 RAM

Any ideas about why i7 3770k CPU does not works in this motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that after many tests i came with a solution.

The CPU i7 3770k finally worked in the Machinist B75 Pro Motherboard, but i had to replace the RAM.

For reasons unknown to me, **Kingstone's Fury HyperX** RAM modules **are not compatible whit the i7 3770k**, but with the i5 3470s, all in the same motherboard. So i had to replace them with generic Hynix RAM modules.

After that, PC started, BIOS recognized the CPU and system started normally.

[image]

Never got an answer from the "official support" by the way.

Answer (score -3):

Try and find a BIOS update.
If that's not possible,, go to the official sites for the 3770 compatible motherboards, and download the chipset drivers  and try them one by one, while rebooting.
This has helped me before in one of these hybrid boards with my i7 3820 CPU.

Comment: How is a Windows driver going to get the author past a problem that happens before the system even performs a POST?

Comment: If the motherboard can´t use the CPU, there is no way to install any driver or access to BIOS... In order to a motherboard start, it requires at least CPU, RAM, BIOS and a basic VGA working

Comment: @quakeglen mainboards do not always require a CPU to POST.

Comment: @music2myear i just make the test, turn it on without the cpu, system just start, but no beeps, and of course, no video. Thanks for the tip anyway